# What is wrong in my answer?

Tags: discussion, specific-answer

What is wrong in my answer?

He ask about "no believing == no kamma".

I answer "kamma can give their resultant, although people do kamma without believing" by the example.

But why vote down?

https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/21710/10100

I don't mind about vote, but I want to know what is the problem in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

People downvote even good honest attempts to answer, just because they disagree with something. And your answer might seem not serious: mosquitos probably are not intelligent enough to hate people; and virtually all people kill mosquitos, so anti-killing people would hardly really hate for that. So your answer might look to someone as a poor attempt to joke. besides, the answer was not very polished and didn't explain the core mechanism of karma, so it was obviously not of very high quality; that might help people to decide to downvote it. Just my guess...

Comment: How can I modify it to be better? For polish.

Comment: @BonnWarapol, when I see high quality answers, I feel: (1) they are well thought over, and point precisely to the most important, core ideas, (2) they are thoroughly formulated, (3) with apparent clarity of mind. In other words, every such answer is like a tiny scientific article or Dharma talk. I myself try to make my answers this way, even though that requires some time and efforts every time. Not sure that I always succeed in that, but probably often to some degree. Check my answers and tell me what you think.

Comment: That is called 4 paṭisambhidā and 5 paṭiveda of ariya.